# Javascript variable declaration and google maps

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, global-variables, declaration

I'm VERY new to javascript but have a reasonable understanding of code processes, I'm struggling with what I think is a global variable issue in Javascript.

This script is within a webpage that runs a php page to pull in some data, then do something with that data.

Two things happen with the data, first it displays it in a cell, which works perfectly so I know variables are being set and code is displaying. The second bit is were I am having problems. I then want to take two of those variables (GPSlat and GPSlon) and pass them to the google maps script to update/recenter the map.

With the code below, if I put in test alerts within the google maps code I get the variable mycenter set as 0, 0 and if I try and alert just GPSlon or GPSlat I get undefined?

I've read a heap on variables, but I'm still missing something. Any gurus out there that can shove me in the right direction?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var GPSlat;
var GPSlon;
var temp;
var chill;
var HI;
var DP;
var pressure;
var heading;
var GPSalt;
var WindDir;
var WindSpd;

//check for browser support
if(typeof(EventSource)!=="undefined") {
    //create an object, passing it the name and location of the server side script
    var eSource = new EventSource("send_sse.php");
    //detect message receipt
    eSource.onmessage = function(event) {
        //write the received data to the page
        //document.getElementById("serverData").innerHTML = event.data;

        var inputdata = event.data;
        var array = inputdata.split("/");

        if (array[0] != null){
        temp = array[0];
        }
        if (array[1] != null){
        chill = array[1];
        }
        if (array[2] != null){
        HI = array[2];
        }
        if (array[3] != null){
        DP = array[3];
        }
        if (array[4] != null){
        hum = array[4];
        }
        if (array[5] != null){
        heading = array[5];
        }   
        if (array[6] != null){
            if (array[6]=="*"){
                GPSlat = 0;
            } else {
                GPSlat = array[6];
            }
        }
        if (array[7] != null){
            if (array[7]=="*"){
                GPSlon = 0;
            } else {
                GPSlon = array[7];
            }
        }
        if (array[8] != null){
            if (array[8]=="*"){
                GPSalt = 0;
            } else {
                GPSalt = array[8];
            }
        }
        if (array[9] != null){
        WindDir = array[9];
        }
        if (array[10] != null){
        WindSpd = array[10];
        }
        if (array[11] != null){
        pressure = array[11];
        }

        var br = "<BR>";
        var output = "Temperature: " + temp + "C" + br + "Wind Chill: " + chill + "C" + br + "Dew Point: " + DP + "C" + br + "Heat Index: " + HI + "C" + br + "Humidity: " + hum + "%" + br + "Pressure: " + pressure + "hPa" + br + br + "Heading: " + heading + br + "Lattitude: " + GPSlat + br + "Longitude: " + GPSlon + br + "Altitude: " + GPSalt + br + br + "Wind Direction: " + WindDir + br + "Wind Speed: " + WindSpd + "kPh"

        document.getElementById("serverData").innerHTML = output;


    }
}
else {
    document.getElementById("serverData").innerHTML="Whoops! No data from Sensor Computer received";
}



//GOOGLE MAPS CODE

var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng([GPSlat],[GPSlon]);

function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
  center:myCenter,
  zoom:10,
  scaleControl:true,
  streetViewControl:true,
  overviewMapControl:true,
   mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
  };


    var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);


var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
  position:myCenter,
  });

marker.setMap(map);
}

if (myCenter!="(0, 0)"){
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    } else {
    document.getElementById("googleMap").innerHTML = "<center><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR>No GPS Data Available</center>"
}
</script>
```

Managed to get the script going based on the below comments and recommendations, end result was passing the string variables as floated objects and using timeout/timeinterval to delay the loading of the map and then continually update the location. Now working correctly!

Final code was:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var GPSlat;
var GPSlon;
var temp;
var chill;
var HI;
var DP;
var pressure;
var heading;
var GPSalt;
var WindDir;
var WindSpd;
var inputdata;
var map;
var marker;


//check for browser support
if(typeof(EventSource)!=="undefined") {

    var eSource = new EventSource("send_sse.php");
    //detect message receipt
        eSource.onmessage = function(event) {
        //write the received data to the page

        inputdata = String(event.data);
        //var inputdata = "23.2/23.2/24.9/9.7/43/NW/-27.471011/153.023449/12.5/S/1.97/1028";
        var array = inputdata.split("/");

        if (array[0] != null){
        temp = array[0];
        }
        if (array[1] != null){
        chill = array[1];
        }
        if (array[2] != null){
        HI = array[2];
        }
        if (array[3] != null){
        DP = array[3];
        }
        if (array[4] != null){
        hum = array[4];
        }
        if (array[5] != null){
        heading = array[5];
        }   
        if (array[6] != null){
            if (array[6]=="*"){
                GPSlat = 0;
            } else {
                GPSlat = array[6];
            }
        }
        if (array[7] != null){
            if (array[7]=="*"){
                GPSlon = 0;
            } else {
                GPSlon = array[7];
            }
        }
        if (array[8] != null){
            if (array[8]=="*"){
                GPSalt = 0;
            } else {
                GPSalt = array[8];
            }
        }
        if (array[9] != null){
        WindDir = array[9];
        }
        if (array[10] != null){
        WindSpd = array[10];
        }
        if (array[11] != null){
        pressure = array[11];
        }

        var br = "<BR>";
        var output = "Temperature: " + temp + "C" + br + "Wind Chill: " + chill + "C" + br + "Dew Point: " + DP + "C" + br + "Heat Index: " + HI + "C" + br + "Humidity: " + hum + "%" + br + "Pressure: " + pressure + "hPa" + br + br + "Heading: " + heading + br + "Lattitude: " + GPSlat + br + "Longitude: " + GPSlon + br + "Altitude: " + GPSalt + br + br + "Wind Direction: " + WindDir + br + "Wind Speed: " + WindSpd + "kPh"

        var dataset = "complete";
        document.getElementById("serverData").innerHTML = output;

    }
}

else {
        document.getElementById("serverData").innerHTML = "Error: No Sensor Data Avaialable";
}








setTimeout(loadScript, 500);
setInterval(updatemarker,10000);


function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(GPSlat),parseFloat(GPSlon)),
  zoom:10,
  scaleControl:true,
  streetViewControl:true,
  overviewMapControl:true,
   mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
  };


map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapProp);


positionmarker()

}


function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&' +
      'callback=initialize';
  document.body.appendChild(script);

}


function positionmarker(){
marker=new google.maps.Marker({
  position:new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(GPSlat),parseFloat(GPSlon)),
  title:"PiCam"
  });

  marker.setMap(map);

}

function updatemarker(){
var newpos = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(GPSlat),parseFloat(GPSlon));
marker.setPosition(newpos);
map.panTo(newpos)
}


</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this Line `var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng([GPSlat],[GPSlon]);`
LatLng always expects float values.so try like this

```
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(GPSlat),parseFloat(GPSlon));
```

Use it and see:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var GPSlat;
var GPSlon;
var temp;
var chill;
var HI;
var DP;
var pressure;
var heading;
var GPSalt;
var WindDir;
var WindSpd;

//check for browser support
if(typeof(EventSource)!=="undefined") {


        var inputdata = "23.2/23.2/24.9/9.7/43/NW/-27.471011/153.023449/12.5/S/1.97/1028";
        var array = inputdata.split("/");

        if (array[0] != null){
        temp = array[0];
        }
        if (array[1] != null){
        chill = array[1];
        }
        if (array[2] != null){
        HI = array[2];
        }
        if (array[3] != null){
        DP = array[3];
        }
        if (array[4] != null){
        hum = array[4];
        }
        if (array[5] != null){
        heading = array[5];
        }   
        if (array[6] != null){
            if (array[6]=="*"){
                GPSlat = 0;
            } else {
                GPSlat = array[6];
            }
        }
        if (array[7] != null){
            if (array[7]=="*"){
                GPSlon = 0;
            } else {
                GPSlon = array[7];
            }
        }
        if (array[8] != null){
            if (array[8]=="*"){
                GPSalt = 0;
            } else {
                GPSalt = array[8];
            }
        }
        if (array[9] != null){
        WindDir = array[9];
        }
        if (array[10] != null){
        WindSpd = array[10];
        }
        if (array[11] != null){
        pressure = array[11];
        }


    }
else {

}

alert(GPSlat);
alert(GPSlon);
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(GPSlat),parseFloat(GPSlon));

function initialize()
{
var mapProp = {
  center:myCenter,
  zoom:10,
  scaleControl:true,
  streetViewControl:true,
  overviewMapControl:true,
   mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
  };


    var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapProp);


var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
  position:myCenter,
  });

marker.setMap(map);
}

if (myCenter!="(0, 0)"){
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    } else {
    document.getElementById("map-canvas").innerHTML = "<center><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR><BR>No GPS Data Available</center>"
}
</script>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas" style="float:left;width:100%;height:100%;">
    </div>

     </body>
```

Comment: Ok that certainly helped, the map now thinks its getting numbers so it tries to render it at least, so thank you VERY much for that as I think that would have been another problem I would have faced. However the variables (using an Alert just before it actually initializes the map) show both values as NaN so I'm assuming it can't read the variable. I tried to echo myCenter right after declaring the variable and it is NaN there as well so it can't access the variable, question is why not???

Comment: Further to this, I'm wondering if because the Google Maps intializes prior to everything else on the page, the values would in fact be null until the script could run to pull the PHP values, but I would expect it to then update once it actually got them read in or have I got this all messed up

Comment: Try with hidden fields.Assign these two values to those variables and use them in creating myCenter,It should work.But before that alert those values which you are assigning to the variables to check whether they really exist or not.

Comment: How do you mean hidden fields? (sorry very new to Java), if I put an alert directly before declaring the myCenter variable I'm getting undefined. Current example would be:

    alert(GPSlat)
alert(GPSlon)
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(GPSlat),parseFloat(GPSlon));

Comment: Apologies, code block looks horrible, should be:
`alert(GPSlat);`
`alert(GPSlon);`  
`var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(GPSlat),parseFloat(GPSlon));`

Comment: Is your var inputdata having the values you are looking for.Just give me the sample data so that i can tell you clearly.

Comment: yes, data is coming through correctly, I've actually put the page up on the net for some other testing, so you can see it here: [link](http://203.219.140.125:8080/strobe/test.html)

Comment: The string that comes in looks like: 23.2/23.2/24.9/9.7/43/NW/-27.471011/153.023449/12.5/S/1.97/1028 the 7th and 8th segments are the co-ordinates, which get passed to the variables and displayed.

Comment: I Think You are not able to get the split-ted data properly.First try to form a string from event.data then use split You will get it.I am going to put the solution in the above Answer which i have given try to solve like that.It is working, to test that simply copy to some html file and run it.I have used the string because i do not had the method which you are using.Sorry if it make inappropriate.

Comment: Thanks for all your help so far, very close now. So I took your example which worked fine for me, and started to port my original code across to find out where it breaks. The reason yours works and mine doesn't is actually that function you didn't have access to. As soon as I add the 2 twos referencing the esource that pulls the data from PHP it breaks `var eSource = new EventSource("send_sse.php");` and `eSource.onmessage = function(event) {`. When I say break, the variables are no longer accessible outside that eSource function, question is how do I make it 'global'?

Comment: Just a further comment, I had tried put `var input data` in at the start, still didn't like that.

Comment: making inputdata global won't help and not required also.you have to make event.data a string so that the split will work fine  then everything will be ok.inputdata you are using only to get var array.your main variables are already Global.

Comment: ok, so I've cast event.data as a string with the following when I set input data: `inputdata = String(event.data);` I get the same result though. I put the an alert inside the function which shows the data correctly, but the alert outside the function shows undefined. What I did notice was the order the alerts presented, I think the function runs after the script loads which means the first time the map loads it is undefined? But then it obviously isn't changing it after the function runs either.

Comment: if loading is the case the read about setTimeOut function and after getting the inputdata wait for some seconds using settimeout the load the map.

Comment: Got it! Timeout function saved the day, I put in a 500ms delay and used set interval and the marker is updating perfectly. Thank you very much for all your help. I'll mark this as the answer and add the final code to the original post so people can see what I did in case anyone needs it. Thanks again!

Comment: Your Welcome. Develope a great site.best wishes.